# MapView not filling the available screen space (FrameLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, mapbox

This is the layout of my `CustomerSearchFragment`.

It has a `CoordinatorLayout` with a `AppBarLayout` and a `ScrollView` with a `FrameLayout` inside.

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.CustomerSearchFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_results_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `FrameLayout` will host `CustomerMapResultsFragment`, whose layout is shown below:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.CustomerMapResultsFragment">

    <com.mapbox.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Actual Behaviour**: the `MapView`'s heigth is just a bunch of pixels (like 16dp).

**Expected behaviour**: the `MapView` has to fill all the available space from the AppBar to the bottom of the screen.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your coordinator layout to ConstraintLayout like below code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.CustomerSearchFragment">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf=parent
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_results_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it setting the 'fillViewPort' to true, but your solution works as well!

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding `android:fillViewport="true"` In the `<ScrollView>`.